# Is it possible to decompose a triangle into quads without splitting edges?

Tags: geometry, puzzle

By quads I mean four sided shapes. You can add vertex anywhere inside the triangle, but you can not add vertex onto existing edges, i.e., splitting them.

I tried but currently it appears to be impossible (see figure below for an attempt). If I guess correctly there must be some topological constraints that make this impossible.[image: splitting attempt]

Comment: I will add that this problem is closely related (actually can be transformed into) graph theory. One basic theorem of graph theory is there is an even number of vertices with odd degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you could divide everything into quadrilaterals. Now, let's count the number of edges in this division; call this number $E$ (in your example, I count $E=15$, but I might have miscounted). Now, each quadrilateral has 4 edges, but with the exception of the 3 edges on the border of the triangle, each edge belongs to 2 quadrilaterals. Therefore, if there are $Q$ quadrilaterals, we have that $4Q = 2E-3$.

But the left side of this equation is even and the right side is odd, leading to a contradiction.

In general, a similar argument will show that you always need an even number of odd-sided faces in any planar graph.

Comment: Thanks, your answer can be made clearer by writing $E = (4Q-3)/2 + 3 = (4Q + 3)/2$, as RHS is not an integer, the decomposition is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Nah, it's impossible. Let's say it were possible, and you had a working dissection. Now imagine you draw four points in each quadrilateral, one on each side. Now of course the number of points is divisible by four, so it is even. On the other hand, you can pair all but three points up with the corresponding point on the other edge, so the number of points is three more than an even number, therefore it must be odd as well.

This is a contradiction, hence the dissection you are looking for is impossible.

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks, and that's a pretty and intuitive drawing!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is quite old, and I believe the other proofs are valid, I have found that with slightly more careful construction this is actually possible!!

[Triangle seemingly split into quads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPLyt.jpg)

The trick here is that the highlighted quadrilateral is technically a pentagon, but lying one of these points along a straight line, it can be made equivalent to a quadrilateral, since at this point we have that the corresponding angle is 180 degrees.

You gotta love maths trickery like this!

Comment: I think your circled point would be considered to be splitting an edge. It's trivial to split any triangle into three quads by splitting the edges, so I take that rule to be one that applies everywhere. https://imgur.com/a/YLYyqk9